# adjusting size of each image in carousel view

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using observable collection and displaying my images in carousel view. I need to adjust them by size..for example the first the biggest and then the images should go smaller. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
<IndicatorView x:Name="indicatorView" IndicatorSize="14"
                       MaximumVisible="6" IndicatorsShape="Circle"
                       Margin="0,20,0,30"
                       IndicatorColor="LightGray"
                       SelectedIndicatorColor="DarkGray"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center">
                        </IndicatorView>
                  <!--Pictures-->
                    <CarouselView Margin="0,0,0,20" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"  x:Name="image" 
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding ImageResults, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                 BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PictureBackground}"
                                 IndicatorView="indicatorView" >
                        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate >
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Image Source="{Binding FieldVisualData}"  WidthRequest="530" HeightRequest="334"  />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    </CarouselView>
```

Comment: Yes.  Determine the size of each image and then sort them accordingly.

Comment: and this should be done in ViewModel?

Comment: It depends on how your project is designed.  But generally, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I find that `Image` uses the `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest`.

There is a easy way to make the size of the images in **CarouselView** consistent, you could set `AspectFit` for each `Image` to show the same effects.

For example:

```
<Image Source="{Binding FieldVisualData}"  
       WidthRequest="530" 
       HeightRequest="334"  
       Aspect="AspectFit"/>
```